# Error con entrada digital arduino

Tags: arduino

Hola tengo una pregunta sobre mi arduino, estoy intentado usar un sensor presencial en un arduino uno, este arroja una señal de 5 volts o 0 v dependiendo si detecta o no un objeto, mi codigo es el siguiente

```
const int pinLED = 12;
int f;
int pirState = LOW;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(pinLED, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop()
{
   f = digitalRead(12);
   if (f == HIGH)   //si está activado
   { 
    if (pirState == LOW)  //si previamente estaba apagado
      {
        Serial.println("Sensor activado");
        pirState = HIGH;
      }
   } 
   else   //si esta desactivado
   {
      if (pirState == HIGH)  //si previamente estaba encendido
      {
        Serial.println("Sensor parado");
        pirState = LOW;
      }
   }
}
```

lo que pasa es que cuando conecto el cable del voltaje del sensor el arduino comienza a imprimir en el serial Sensor activado sensor parado, como si se estuvieran haciendo cambios muy rapido de voltaje cuando ni siquiera estoy mandando voltaje, incluso si tengo conectado solo el cable hace esto, no se si sea un error en la programacion y de mi arduino si alguien puede ayudarme gracias.

El error que pienso yo que puede ser es que no esta leyendo un 0 y en si o cualquier voltaje tantito arriba de 0 hace que este dispare un cambio en el if donde detecta voltaje y no detecta, por que al mandarle los 5v se detiene y se queda solo Sensor activado, mientras que cuando se quitan estos 5v se hace el error este que comento

Comment: el problema está con tu código, El led tiene que tener un pinmode tipo OUTPUT y el sensor PIR tiene que tener INPUT

Comment: Por cierto si intentaste [este ejemplo](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/using-a-pir-w-arduino), tienes que separar los pines del led y del sensor, ya que no son el mismo

Comment: solo tome la parte de el input como se ve ahi por que no uso ese sensor uso uno de presencia como digo y este me arroja o 5 o 0 v si se llma pinLED es por que solo lo tome y lo ajuste para mi programa la variable es entrada asi que eso nada que ver

Comment: a que te refieres con "sensor de presencia"?  puedes poner al menos un link del tipo de sensor o el código de serie?

Comment: es un omron E3Z-LL 88